# Convert locations from ways to nodes?

Tags: openstreetmap, kml, export

When querying OSM through OverpassTurbo, I notice some locations are ploted as polygons (closed ways) instead of nodes, which makes ill-suited for displaying them in eg. Google My Maps:

```
WAYS
<Placemark><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>1.2576092,49.2925736 … 1.2576092,49.2925736</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></Placemark>

NODE
<Placemark><Point><coordinates>3.6255999,48.3479532</coordinates></Point></Placemark>
```

Is there a simple way to turn all polygons into nodes, either with a GUI application like JOSM or a Python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than tweaking the KML result, why not change your original overpass query to only return points? That's **way** easier to do:

```
[out:json][timeout:25][bbox:{{bbox}}];
(
  node["tourism"="camp_site"];
  way["tourism"="camp_site"];
  relation["tourism"="camp_site"];
);
out center;
```

Export the result to KML and you're all set.

Try it in overpass turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/p2h